# how to link the formula to the column that was filtered?

Tags: vba, excel

Currently I'm trying to enter this formula in the cell with vba.

```
Selection.AutoFilter Field:=10, Criteria1:="*FG*"

Set Rng = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("J2:J" & lastRow)

Set TopVisibleCell = Rng.Offset(1).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Cells(1)

    TopVisibleCell.Formula = _
     "=IF(ISERROR(LEFT(I2,SEARCH("" - "",I2)-1)),I2,LEFT(I2,SEARCH("" - "",I2)-1))"
```

I'm trying to enter the formula in column P after i have filtered column I which is field=10. The topvisiblecell.formula is entered to the column P. The formula will remain the same after I filtered column I. Let say, I filtered column I which starts from row 200 but in column P the formula is still I2. how to change by following the column I which i filtered ?

Comment: I'm confused. Column I is column 9, not 10, and your code adds the formula to column J, not P. Can you clarify your intention? (I think the solution will be to use `.FormulaR1C1' so you can specify a column number)

Answer (score 0):

I am using this :

```
    .Range("A:Z").AutoFilter Field:=10, Criteria1:="10"
.Range("B2:B200").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Value = "=A" & .UsedRange.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Row & "/2"
```

this would put formula "=A + row number + /2 in all B rows, therefore

```
B2=A2/2, B3=A3/2
```

etc ..